# How to catch specific error code on JS SDK connecting to horizon

Tags: horizon, accounts, javascript-sdk, error

I use Javascript SDK to connect to Horizon. It works, but I also would like the specific error if it doesn't work. See my code below.

How can I access the specific code returned from horizon (e.g. 404)? Right now I only get "Error".

Thanks in advance.

---

```
// --- check if account is active
server.accounts()
    .accountId(publicKey)
    .call()
    .then(function (accountResult) 
      ...
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        alert(err);
        document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = 'Account not valid or inactive1!';
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

The error object contains `response` field with HTTP response details from the server. You can refer to `response.status` to retrieve the status code.

```
if (err.response && err.response.status === 404) {
  console.error('Account does not exist.')
}
else {
  console.error(err)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, just what I was missing. I sent you some lumen on your expert donation address.